# How to change URL's in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know this topic already been here, but I need help because I cant find an answer.

Here is my problem:

I am trying to change urls

```
example.com.au/admin/pages.php 

to 

example.com.au/admin/pages  (without .php extention)
```

then I am trying to:

```
example.com.au/admin/edit.php?id=1 

to 

example.com.au/admin/edit/1
```

I have this .htaccess, please helkp me sort this problem. thanks

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^edit/([^/.]+)/?$ edit.php?id=$1
```

Comment: @Patric Think before posting here... and read my question...

Comment: is there a reason why you don't want to use a framework / front controller instead of trying to map every url individually?

Comment: you should use `mvc` design pattern. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller, https://github.com/panique/php-mvc

Comment: Why everyone sticking to their frameworks, they sux mate.

Comment: We are only suggesting you, IGNORE IF IT IS NOT HELPFUL.

Comment: DUDE I need help with Rewrite Rules not freaking other crap you posting here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^edit/(.*)/?$ edit.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: this removes .php extention only but url admin/pages/edit/1 not working still

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS WORKING, thanks everyone got my answer my self.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^admin/pages/edit/(.+)$ admin/pages/edit.php?id=$1 [L]
```